# mysql function display users under 25?

Tags: php, mysql

can someone help i am trying to get my mysql query to display all the users on my site who are 18-25 and its currently doing that but it's echoing out the same result/same user about 20 times.

i only want to display each result/each user once in the query. can someone please show me where im going wrong thank you.

the age is currentlt recorded in the database as a varchar (11) im using age seperate from my date of brith which is a time_stamp but i need the age to be set up seperate from the date of birth so im using a varchar column.

so to be clear im trying to display all users under 25 (without it duplicating the result and echoing out more than one user per result)

function:

```
function categories_agegroup_under25() {
            global $connection;
            $query = "SELECT *
                        FROM ptb_users, ptb_stats
                        WHERE ptb_users.account_type = \"User\" AND ptb_users.account_status = \"Active\" AND ptb_stats.user_id = ptb_users.id
                        AND ptb_stats.user_age='18' OR  ptb_stats.user_age='19' OR ptb_stats.user_age='21' OR  ptb_stats.user_age='22' OR ptb_stats.user_age='23' OR  ptb_stats.user_age='24' OR  ptb_stats.user_age='25'           

                        ORDER BY ptb_stats.user_age DESC
                        LIMIT 0,40";
            $categories_under25_set = mysql_query($query, $connection);
            confirm_query($categories_under25_set);
            return $categories_under25_set;
        }
```

php:

```
 <?php
        $categories_under25_set = categories_agegroup_under25();
        while ($age = mysql_fetch_array($categories_under25_set)) {


            echo"
            <div class=\"boxgrid caption\">
            <a href=\"profile.php?id={$age['id']}\"><img width=140px height= 180px src=\"data/photos/{$age['id']}/_default.jpg\"/></a>
            <div class=\"cover boxcaption\">
            <h58> {$age['display_name']}, {$age['user_age']}</h58>
            </div>
            </div>";
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: why a varchar of 11 for the age, and not an int(3) ?

Comment: @John That was the second thing I noticed after the table cross product. This needs a rewrite lol

Comment: Two things: 1) time_stamp won't show users that were born before 1970. 2) Storing the age *and* the DoB is bad database normalisation.

Answer (score 0):

ptb_stats.user_age between 18 and 25
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
SELECT DISTINCT username FROM ...
```

Also the reason you get duplicated results is because you use `FROM table1, table2` where instead you should be using a `JOIN` statement as the first statement will do a table cross product.

Answer (score 0):

you are having comflict with `AND` and `OR`

try this

```
   SELECT *
                    FROM ptb_users, ptb_stats
                    WHERE ptb_users.account_type = \"User\" 
                    AND ptb_users.account_status = \"Active\" 
                    AND ptb_stats.user_id = ptb_users.id
                    AND ptb_stats.user_age in (18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25)        
                    GROUP BY ptb_stats.user_id
                    ORDER BY ptb_stats.user_age DESC
                    LIMIT 0,40
```